Comparing performance of GStreamer plugins
Can someone tell me how to compare the performance of a GStreamer plugin with one from NVidia Accelerated GStreamer?  Any plugin.  I am new to video/audio drivers.  I have played with the GStreamer examples and also run some of the tutorial code on the GStreamer site so not a total novice.

For video processing throughput you may evaluate it with fpsdisplaysink:
# H264 encoding of 1280x720@30 with x264enc
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! h264parse ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=fakesink text-overlay=0 sync=0 -v

# H264 encoding of 1280x720@30 with NVENC (not available with Orin Nano)
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! fpsdisplaysink video-sink=fakesink text-overlay=0 sync=0 -v

Let it run for 10s for more accurate results.
You may also use htop or tegrastats at the same time in a separate terminal for monitoring ressources usage.

Thanks so much!  I ran this on my Jetson Orin and got the following results.  I don't quite know how to interpret them since the nvv4l2h264enc is giving me more frames rendered than the x264enc.  Here is the output:
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 12, dropped: 0, current: 23.57, average: 23.57
the above is output for first x264enc pipeline
the below is output for the nvvidconv pipeline
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 133, dropped: 0, current: 264.20, average: 264.20

So x264enc can encode this resolution up to 23 fps, while nvv4l2h264enc can encode the same up to 264 fps. The latter is about 10 times faster, while using less CPU.
